# connecting angular web app to firebase

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, angular, firebase

I watn to connect my web application to firebase,and I have VPN but after running, my dashboard component is not displayed and there are some errors :

An error occurred :Response app/hero.service.js:57
ERROR Error:node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1091
Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL:
https://my firebase database name /.json

This is my code:
**DashboardComponent:**

```
        import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import { Hero }        from './hero';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './dashboard.component.css' ]
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Hero[] = [];

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
      .then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(1, 5));

  }



}
```

**hero.service.ts**

```
          import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { Hero } from './hero';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {

  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  private heroesUrl = private heroesUrl = "https://tour-of-heroes-bcc7b.firebaseio.com/.json";  // URL to web api

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
               .toPromise()
               .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
               .catch(this.handleError);
  }


  getHero(id: number): Promise<Hero> {
    const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get(url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json().data as Hero)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  delete(id: number): Promise<void> {
    const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.delete(url, {headers: this.headers})
      .toPromise()
      .then(() => null)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  create(name: string): Promise<Hero> {
    return this.http
      .post(this.heroesUrl, JSON.stringify({name: name}), {headers: this.headers})
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => res.json().data as Hero)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  update(hero: Hero): Promise<Hero> {
    const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${hero.id}`;
    return this.http
      .put(url, JSON.stringify(hero), {headers: this.headers})
      .toPromise()
      .then(() => hero)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>Angular Tour of Heroes</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Polyfills -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>


  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>

<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "my firebase project apikey",
    authDomain: "my firebase projec domain name",
    databaseURL: "my firebase projec database name",
    projectId: "my firebase projec ID",
    storageBucket: "my firebase projec storage",
    messagingSenderId: "my firebase projec senderId"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>


  </head>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.module.ts

```
     import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

// Imports for loading & configuring the in-memory web api
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService }  from './in-memory-data.service';

import { AppComponent }         from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent }   from './dashboard.component';
import { HeroesComponent }      from './heroes.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent }  from './hero-detail.component';
import { HeroService }          from './hero.service';
import { HeroSearchComponent }  from './hero-search.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    HeroesComponent,
    HeroSearchComponent
  ],
  providers: [ HeroService ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: The problem is here - `private heroesUrl = "https://my firebase database name/.json";`

Comment: here should be a real url to you database in firebase

Comment: Thanke you so much.my real cod is : private heroesUrl = "https://tour-of-heroes-bcc7b.firebaseio.com/.json";     but it dose not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update url `heroesUrl = "https://tour-of-heroes-bcc7b.firebaseio.com/.json"`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I see that you have used `InMemoryWebApi`. You need to remove the following line from your `NgModule`, it will interfere with your "real" http-requests. So remove from `NgModule` the following line:

```ts
InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService)
```

Then Notice the extra `private heroesUrl` in your Service:

```ts
private heroesUrl = private heroesUrl = "https://tour-of-heroes-bcc7b.firebaseio.com/.json";
```

should be:

```ts
private heroesUrl = "https://tour-of-heroes-bcc7b.firebaseio.com/.json";
```

Next your `getHeroes` function in your service. The JSON you are receiving, is an array, so there is no object `data` in your response, that would contain the array you are looking for, so change:

```ts
.then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
```

to

```ts
.then(response => response.json() as Hero[])
```

I think I have then pinpointed the errors (hopefully). Here's a little

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/gkFunf5C2o78RCWyWSMQ?p=preview)

---

### **UPDATE:**

The new error `slice is not a function` is caused by you having changed the request url, so the data changed and now we are no longer dealing with an array, but an object of objects. Therefore you need to create a loop and extract each object and push them to your `heroes` array. So your subscribe would then look like this:

```ts
this.heroService.getHeroes()
  .then(data => {
    // iterate the object and push each object from inside that object to your array
    for(let obj in data) {
      this.heroes.push(data[obj])
    }
    console.log(this.heroes)
    this.heroes = this.heroes.slice(1, 5)
  });
```

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/SFxPLzjpVrWL5hHy0EoS?p=preview)

Comment: Hi.Thanke you.When I changed my code there was another error:    node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:1091 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: heroes.slice is not a function
TypeError: heroes.slice is not a function
    at eval (app/dashboard.component.js:22)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:365)
    at Object.onInvoke (node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4132)
      could you help me?

Comment: Could you fork the plunker with your code, so that I could take a look?

Comment: I see no forked version here... ? Last update 2 days ago... http://plnkr.co/edit/gkFunf5C2o78RCWyWSMQ?p=preview Check it please and I'll take a look :)

Comment: You are right.I made a mistake.I made a new plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/58HIbbkYulBl5KBd9h7F?p=preview

Comment: I updated my answer, the request was for another url, and the shape of the data is different than the first url. But now it should work :)

Comment: Thank you for help it worked.I wana  consult of you to improve my coding as much possible.
How can I directly be in chat with to get more help if it is not bother you?

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked, and since it solved your issue, could you kindly accept the answer by clicking the grey tick under the voting of this answer? Here's how if it's unclear: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235 :) As per further assistance, sure I could help with some (minor) issues whenever possible, keeping in mind that I would not be your private assistant :D You can reach me on fb: @aa.jii.13